# Calling Pdf417 phonegap/cordova plugin in Ionic

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm having trouble successfully calling the [Pdf417 phonegap/cordova plugin](https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap) scan function in demo mode within an Ionic application. I'm testing the plugin with Ionic View on iOS.

[Here is a linked Github repository](http://embed.plnkr.co/AE8oGawQgThfGHEtozD0/preview) containing a simplified version of the application with just one state and controller.

Unfortunately I'm completely confused as to why this is not working
when I test it. I get an error saying 'cordova is not defined'
in the browser, which I would expect because cordova plugins should
404 in browser, but it's not working in Ionic View either.

I've installed the plugin successfully with 'cordova plugin add (location of pdf417 git repo') prior to attempting to make this work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't have much experience
so I may be on the wrong track in general, and sorry in advance if I am. Any guidance would at all would be helpful. If I'm unclear with anything I'll gladly elaborate. I'm sure I may have missed some needed information.

Here is my app.js from the application:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
/**
* RUN
*/

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
})

/**
* CONTROLLERS
*/
//Workflow Controller
.controller('workflowCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPlatform', '$ionicPopup',
function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    //***PDF417 SCANNER***
    function hex2a(hex) {
        var str = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
            str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
        }
        return str;
    }
    var types = ["PDF417", "QR Code"];
    var options = {
        beep : true,  // Beep on
        noDialog : true,
        uncertain : false, //Recommended
        quietZone : false, //Recommended
        highRes : false, //Recommended
        inverseScanning: false,
        frontFace : false
    };
    var licenseiOs = null;
    var licenseAndroid = null;
    $scope.barcodeResult;
    $scope.fields;
    $scope.scan = function() {
      $ionicPopup.alert({
        title:'Scan Button Clicks',
      });
      console.log('Scan Button Clicks');
      cordova.plugins.pdf417Scanner.scan(
        // Register the callback handler
        function callback(scanningResult) {
          // handle cancelled scanning
          if (scanningResult.cancelled == true) {
            console.log('Scanner cancelled');
            $scope.warnings = "Cancelled";
            return;
          }
          // Obtain list of recognizer results
          var resultList = scanningResult.resultList;
          // Iterate through all results
          for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
            // Get individual resilt
            var recognizerResult = resultList[i];
            if (recognizerResult.resultType == "Barcode result") {
              // handle Barcode scanning result
              if (typeof(recognizerResult.raw) != "undefined" && recognizerResult.raw != null) {
                var raw = hex2a(recognizerResult.raw);
              }
              $scope.barcodeResult = {
                "Data": recognizerResult.data,
                "Raw": raw,
                "Type": recognizerResult.type
              };
            } else if (recognizerResult.resultType == "USDL result") {
              // handle USDL parsing result
              var fields = recognizerResult.fields;
              $scope.fields = {
                /** Personal information */
                "USDL version": fields[kPPAamvaVersionNumber],
                "Family name": fields[kPPCustomerFamilyName],
                "First name": fields[kPPCustomerFirstName],
                "Date of birth": fields[kPPDateOfBirth],
                "Sex": fields[kPPSex],
                "Eye color": fields[kPPEyeColor],
                "Height": fields[kPPHeight],
                "Street": fields[kPPAddressStreet],
                "City": fields[kPPAddressCity],
                "Jurisdiction": fields[kPPAddressJurisdictionCode],
                "Postal code": fields[kPPAddressPostalCode],
                /** License information */
                "Issue date": fields[kPPDocumentIssueDate],
                "Expiration date": fields[kPPDocumentExpirationDate],
                "Issuer ID": fields[kPPIssuerIdentificationNumber],
                "Jurisdiction version": fields[kPPJurisdictionVersionNumber],
                "Vehicle class": fields[kPPJurisdictionVehicleClass],
                "Restrictions": fields[kPPJurisdictionRestrictionCodes],
                "Endorsments": fields[kPPJurisdictionEndorsementCodes],
                "Customer ID": fields[kPPCustomerIdNumber]
              };
            }
          }
        },
        // Register the error callback
        function errorHandler(err) {
          console.log("error: " + err);
          $scope.warnings = err;
        },
        types, options, licenseiOs, licenseAndroid
      );
    };
    //***END PDF417 SCANNER***
  });
}])

/**
* ROUTING
*/
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
{

  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style('striped');
  $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/workflow');

  $stateProvider
  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'partials/tab.html'
    })
  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
    .state('tab.workflow', {
      url: '/workflow',
      views: {
        'tab-workflow': {
          templateUrl: 'partials/tab-workflow.html',
          controller: 'workflowCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
});
```

Also, here is my system log when I click on the button to start up pdf417 with 'ionic emulate ios' to run the simulator.

```
THREAD WARNING: [‘Pdf416Scanner’] took ’12.760742’ ms.
Plugin should use a background thread.
```

UPDATE: This error is expected as the peripheral is not available in the emulator, although I still have no function in when testing in ionic view (currently with iOS).

Comment: I just tried to use it and I had no problem. When you use Cordova naked, you use Cordova commands but if you want to use Ionic, that's better to use only Ionic commands to avoid unexpected behaviors. Also this plugin is strangely structured (a plugin inside an example, this is a first !).

Comment: Thank you for checking it out. Should I try testing with Xcode rather than testing in ionic view? It's completely unresponsive in ionic vew so far. Also, I know it's quite weird to put the plugin into the controller. It really should be in a service, but I wanted to minimize the variables in my issue as I'm already confused as to why the plugin not being responsive for me.

Comment: I wasn't talking about your code but about the pdf417 plugin ;) Normally what is within Pdf417 directory should be at the root of the plugin, so it would allow to install it via a simple `cordova|ionic plugin add https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap`. Anyway, there are no general rules about where to inject your plugins services. It really depends on what this services does. Indeed under iOS it always worth a try to build under Xcode when it's not working. This is at least how it works under Cordova alone. Did you try to run it without this plugin ?

Comment: And I forgot, try also not to load JS and CSS via http, but locally, since it can lead to many problems linked with CSP (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/). This what I did to test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to you your problem is very simple: Ionic View only supports a limited number of plugins (at the moment) and your is not in the list.

It started off supporting even less but more have been added.

Here is a relevant link: http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/view-usage

I would suggest deploying to a device via USB.